# Angular JS form post reload the page

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, zurb-foundation

I am new to angular I am trying to post my form but as I click on my button my form get reloaded with the form data on URL,I am not able to view my console data.
here I  wrote the code.

```
 <div class="large-7 columns" ng-app="registerform">
                  <div class="sign-up-container" ng-controller="registeruserdetail">
                    <h4 class="title">Not a member? {{2+2}}</h4>
                    <form ng-submit="userdata()">

                        <label>
                          <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="registeruser.firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
                        </label>

                        <label>
                          <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="registeruser.lastname" placeholder="Lastname">
                        </label>

                        <label>
                          <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="registeruser.email" placeholder="E-mail Address">
                        </label>

                        <label>
                          <input type="text" name="cemail" ng-model="registeruser.confirmemail" placeholder="Confirm E-mail Address">
                        </label>

                        <label>
                          <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="registeruser.password" placeholder="Password">
                        </label>

                        <label>
                          <input type="password" name="cpassword" ng-model="registeruser.confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                        </label>

                        <span class="gender">Gender :</span>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" ng-model="registeruser.gender" value="male" id="male" ><label for="male">Male</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" ng-model="registeruser.gender" id="female"><label for="female">Female</label>

                        <div class="button-holder">
                            <button class="" type="submit"><img src="img/sign-up.jpg" /></button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>  
                </div>
```

custom.js

```
var validationApp = angular.module('registerform', []);

validationApp.controller('registeruserdetail',function($scope,$http){
//$scope.registeruser={};
    $scope.userdata=function(){
        console.log($scope.registeruser);

        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:'/intern/admin-panel/public/register',
            data:$.param($scope.registeruser),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},


        }).success(function(response) {
       console.log(response);

         alert('hi');
    }).error(function(response) {
       console.log(response);

       alert('hello');
    });
    alert('here i am');
    };

});
```

if i apply alert(here i am) below the $http method, on submit my code takes me here ie, this alert pops but not getting either of the other records.
can any one please suggest me what mistake i am committing with the code.
Edited:
I found the reason for this as if i am applying the controller div on page i may able to process as i want to , but when i am applying the same controller div on reveal model i am not able to process i am getting the issue as i mention above.How can i resolve this issue or reveal model as well.

Comment: Code you posted looks ok to me. Are you sure error is not generating form somewhere else?

Comment: i am not getting even the alert it just reload my page, i tried almost everything but not getting what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you including angularjs and JQuery files?

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slippry.min.js"></script>
 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
 here is what all i am including @ footer

Answer (score 3):

I found answer to my question self.

All code was fine just i need to prevent the default action of reveal model submit form which goes like this.

```
  <form ng-submit="userdata($event)">  <!-- Pass event-->

                        <label>
                          <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="registeruser.firstname" placeholder="Firstname">


                </label>
```

.
.
.

and
custom.js

```
$scope.userdata=function(e){ //add event 
         e.preventDefault();  //make change here
         console.log('hi i am here');
        //console.log($scope.registeruser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see here example : http://jsbin.com/xejek/2/

```
validationApp.controller('registeruserdetail',function($scope,$http){

  $scope.userdata=function(){
        console.log($scope.registeruser);

        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:'/intern/admin-panel/public/register',
            data:$scope.registeruser,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},


        }).then(function(response) {
       console.log(response);

         alert('data posted');
    },function(response) {
       console.log(response);

       alert("can't post data");
    });

    };

});
```

Comment: thanx for the help but still i am getting my page reloaded not even my alert blocking the page from getting reload.

Comment: @user284303 that really wired try to copy code from http://jsbin.com/xejek/3/edit into your project

Comment: my form div is on reveal model,is it making difference?

Comment: @user284303 if it is outside controller yes it makes difference